# Write into 2 table in same DB in 2 different background worker process

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a winforms app which will write data into 2 different tables in same DB. My timer will count every one second. When the first machine is ready to give data, I will get it and write to the first table.  When the machine 2 is ready as well, I will get it and write data to the second table. I put these two inserting processes in two different background worker processes. But I keep getting an error "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting."  Below is my code.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readMachinewidth();
    }

 private void readMachinewidth()
    {
            if(M1 == "true")
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            if(M2 == "true")
            {
                backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
    }


   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!oData.saveM1ProcessQty("M1", "M1"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("M1 - Database Error");
            return;
        }
    }

     private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (oData.saveM2ProcessQty("M2", "M2"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("M2 - Database Error");
            return;
        }
    }
```

May I know how I can fix it? How I can make the winforms can write data in two different tables in almost the same time in same database.  I expect it is the connection open issue.  But I can't figure out how to fix it.  When write table 1 data the connection is open while at the same time the data for Machine 2 may be ready to write as well.

My data insertion function

```
 public Boolean saveM1ProcessQty(string M1, string M1a)
    {
        try
        {
            string sSQL = "";
            SqlCommand oCmd;

            sSQL = "INSERT INTO xxx(M1, M1-1)VALUES('";
            sSQL = sSQL + M1+ "','" + M1a+ "')";

            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Open();

            oCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oConn.ConnectionLocal);
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            oCmd.Dispose();

            return true;

        }
        catch(SqlException sqlex)
        {
            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            Common.ErrorLog("M1 - " + sqlex.Message.ToString());
            return false;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            Common.ErrorLog("M1 - " + ex.Message.ToString());
            return false;               
        }
    }

public Boolean saveM2ProcessQty(string M2, string M2a)
    {
        try
        {
            string sSQL = "";
            SqlCommand oCmd;

            sSQL = "INSERT INTO xxx(M1, M1-1)VALUES('";
            sSQL = sSQL + M2+ "','" + M2a+ "')";

            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Open();

            oCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oConn.ConnectionLocal);
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            oCmd.Dispose();

            return true;

        }
        catch(SqlException sqlex)
        {
            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            Common.ErrorLog("M2 - " + sqlex.Message.ToString());
            return false;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            oConn.ConnectionLocal.Close();
            Common.ErrorLog("M2 - " + ex.Message.ToString());
            return false;               
        }
    }
```

My Connection class

```
   public SqlConnection ConnectionLocal
    {
        get
        {
            if(_localConn == null)
            {                
                string sconnstring =  
                      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ToString();
                _localConn = new SqlConnection(sconnstring);
            }
            return _localConn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: multiple machines writing to multiple tables is irrelevant in this case. You simply have a bug in our code. If you were running just one app I expect that the same bug would occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when you are not calling `SqlConnection.Open()`. It has nothing to do with concurrency. Without seeing your actual database access code, I can't help you much more than that. But somewhere along the line, the connection is being created in memory but not connected.

**Edit:**

In re to a comment, here's the code with `using` blocks as appropriate. I also took the liberty of parameterizing your query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```
public Boolean saveM1ProcessQty(string M1, string M1a)
{
    try
    {
        string sSQL = "INSERT INTO xxx (M1, M1-1) VALUES ('@m1, @m1a')";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conn));
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", M1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1a", M1a);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Common.ErrorLog("M1 - " + ex.Message.ToString());
        return false;               
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, I has add my database access code.  Please help to check what is the error.  Thank you very much

Comment: Alright, first off, you should be disposing of your connection and commands via `using` blocks. That will be way more reliable than doing it manually as you are. Second, is there a reason you're creating only one connection object, using it, disposing of it, then trying to use it again? Why not just make a new connection for each time you need one?

Comment: Hi Matthew, do you mind give sample code how I can dispose the connection via using blocks?  For connection, do you means every time I need perform insertion, I create a new connection?